# Calling python script from C# project failing: SetProcessDpiAwareness(2) failed

Tags: c#, python, matplotlib

I have a C# project that calls a python script using a Process:

```
var scriptRunProcess = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "Python",
        Arguments = file,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = false
    }
};
```

This python script builds a series of graphs using matplotlib and saves them as a PDF using matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages.

When running this project manually through Visual Studio everything works fine. When I try to run this program as an automated task using windows task scheduler it crashed in the python script with the error:
SetProcessDpiAwareness(2) failed: COM error 0xffffffff80070005  (Unknown error 0x0ffffffff80070005), using 2

I've tried searching this error with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can import ptvsd in your script, then wait for debugger to attach. In PTVS attach to this process. Debugger can give you more info.